# save excel file including YYMMYY HHMM

Tags: excel, vba

unable to follow below syntax

FileName = Format(Date, "yymmdd.hhmm") & " TRI" & ".xlsx"

result is "230111 0000 TRI"
what i need is if 9am result to be "230111.0900 TRI"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will be DateTime.Now()

FileName = Format(DateTime.Now(), "yymmdd hhmm") & " TRI" & ".xlsx"

Comment: Your format is incorrect. It does not match the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

> FileName = Format(Date, "yymmdd.HHmm") & " TRI.xlsx"

```
Sub Test()
    Const ExpectedResult As String = "230111.0900 TRI.xlsx"
    Const TestDate As Date = #1/11/2023 9:00:00 AM#

    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Format(TestDate, "yymmdd.HHmm") & " TRI.xlsx"
    Debug.Print FileName, "Test: "; IIf(FileName = ExpectedResult, "PASS", "FAIL")

End Sub
```

[image: Immediate Window Result]

Note:  `Format()` is something that we use a lot as programmers. It would be advantageous to read the docs:  [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008925)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: A hardcoded date is not what the questioneer expects.

Comment: @Gustav I was merely demonstrating a better way of going about developing than visually inspecting the output in the immediate window. I would like to point out that the OP state **what i need is if 9am result to be "230111.0900 TRI"**.  Could you please post   a code sample with a dynamic date that delivers this exact output?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but: _what I need is if 9am_ - yes, and that is different from _what i need is as 9am_. Thus, I believe _9 AM_ is an example value.

Comment: @Gustav  Your right.  The devil is in the details.  Happy coding!